# How to make a c++ program which is waiting for some event, appear responsive?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 to develop a windows form application using c++.

This program waits for an event like connection request and displays a message

But this program is shown as "not responding" in windows task manager.

Is there any way to make the program appear responsive ??

Comment: Does the waiting happen in the background? Standard approach would be to do the waiting in a seperate thread and keep the rest of the application running, but it depends on your needs and expectations if this is correct.

Comment: I second @crashmstr. You need to pop events off the event loop in order to appear responsive (in regards to Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard practice for this situation is to use multi-threading. Create a background thread to wait for the connection request or whatever event you need that might cause the primary thread to block.

This allows the user interface of your application to remain responsive. If you don't use a thread, the primary UI thread will be blocked waiting for the request and can't handle other events such as drawing the form, responding to window events, etc.

In Windows programming, any activity that is going to take a significant amount of time should be threaded. This isn't a hard rule, but a pragmatic amount of threading will make a world of different in giving your application a smooth, responsive feel. The primary thread should be reserved for drawing and handling user interaction.

A Google search will give you plenty of examples, but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12740/Threads-with-Windows-Forms-Controls-in-Managed-C) is a decent one to get you started.